# Reading competencies with valence

Tags: valence

I am trying to read competencies from a course offering with the action referenced here http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/competency.html.

GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/competencies/structure

The documentation states it first appears in Learning Environment v10.4.0. Not sure what api version to use since it is not mentioned. I have tried LE v1.4 and LE v.1.5 but both version return a not found error.

Is this action available even if unstable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The le value to use for the version is "unstable".
The competencies need to be approved before they will show in valence. 
Another thing, to see them in related courses, the competency needs to be shared down.

It now works.

Paul,